# shiny module with observeEvent updates based on previous inputs

Tags: r, shiny, module, shiny-reactivity

I have an app which creates boxes. Each box has a button that triggers a modal. The modal has inputs which the user changes and then a button which triggers an action based on those inputs (basically just uploading to a database). Because each box has a different specification, I wrote a module and then loop thru a list, creating a box for each element. This works fine.

However, the flow in the modal and observeEvent has a flaw: the first run thru I get the desired results, but on the second occasion in the same box (same id module), after pressing the modal button to update, it will not use the new inputs, but rather what happened in the first run. I am guessing it has something to do with the namespace/observeEvent combination as I might be triggering the event with a "stored" namespace? Would I need to somehow "flush" the namespace after every update? Anyway, any help appreciated as it gets confusing fast with all the namespace/modules combinations.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- navbarPage(
  'page', collapsible = TRUE,
  tabPanel("test",
           useSweetAlert(),
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(), 
             mainPanel(
               uiOutput('all_products_ui')
               )
           )
  )) # end navbar

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  list_products <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

  # Now, I will create a UI for all the products
  output$all_products_ui <- renderUI({
    r <- tagList()
    progress_move <- 0
    for(k in 1:length( list_products )){
                     r[[k]] <- ExistingProductUI(id = k, product = list_products[[k]] ) 
    }
    r
  })
  
  # handlers duplicate a call to module depending on the id of ExistingProductUI 
  handlers <- list()
  observe(
    handlers <<- lapply(seq.int(length( list_products )), 
                        function(i) {
                          callModule(ExistingProductUpdate, 
                                     id = i, 
                                     product = list_products[[i]] )
                        })
  )  
  handlers
  
}) # end of server ---- 


# UI module ------------------------------------------------------
ExistingProductUI <- function(id, product){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  box(title = as.character(p$title), 
      product["title"], 
      footer = tagList(
        actionBttn(
          inputId = ns("change_selected"), label = "change"),
       )
    )
}
# server module ------------------------------------------------------
ExistingProductUpdate <- function(input, output, session, product){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  
  observeEvent(input$change_selected, {
   # when box button is clicked for this product (id)
    # FIRST: show a modal
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "what do you want to change?",
        tagList(
          radioGroupButtons(inputId = ns("change_selected_choice"), labels = "change x", choices = c(1,2,3,4)),
          sliderInput(ns("change_selected_pct"), "change y:", min = -50, max = 100, value = 0, step = 5)
        ),
        easyClose = TRUE, 
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton(ns("change_selected_submit"), "submit!", icon = icon("check")),
          modalButton("never mind")
        )
      )
    )
    # SECOND: when change_selected_submit is clicked, 
    observeEvent(input$change_selected_submit, {
      
      # do some calculations with product using what I inputed in modal --- 
      # then, update a table ---- 
      functionToUploadThings(product, input$change_selected_choice)
      
    # THIRD: Close with a confirmation
      sendSweetAlert(
        session,
        title = "Success!",
        type = "success",
        btn_labels = "Ok",
        closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
        width = NULL
      )
    }) 
    
  }) 
}
```

Comment: when trying to run the App I get : Page/Test + Error: plot.New hasnt be called yet. Did you check your code after restarting an R session? Thanks for your feedback

Comment: where is `p$title` defined in the ui module? Input of the module is `product`, not `p`

Comment: Do you use `box` from the `shinydashboard` package in the module UI?

Comment: if i apply similar repairments as starja and add `print(input$change_selected_choice)` to `observeEvent(input$change_selected_submit, {...}` the values update correctly each time the button is clicked. Does the problem persist for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution that works. The problem was that you nested your `observeEvent` in the module. I'm not entirely sure why this led to problems, some values weren't processed correctly. However, you don't need to nest the `observeEvent`, the second one gets also triggered by the `actionButton` in the modal when it is by its own. Additionally, I included a `removeModal` before the success notification is shown:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- navbarPage(
  'page', collapsible = TRUE,
  tabPanel("test",
           useSweetAlert(),
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(), 
             mainPanel(
               uiOutput('all_products_ui')
             )
           )
  )) # end navbar

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  list_products <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
  
  # Now, I will create a UI for all the products
  output$all_products_ui <- renderUI({
    r <- tagList()
    progress_move <- 0
    for(k in 1:length( list_products )){
      r[[k]] <- ExistingProductUI(id = k, product = list_products[[k]] ) 
    }
    r
  })
  
  # handlers duplicate a call to module depending on the id of ExistingProductUI 
  handlers <- list()
  observe(
    handlers <<- lapply(seq.int(length( list_products )), 
                        function(i) {
                          callModule(ExistingProductUpdate, 
                                     id = i, 
                                     product = list_products[[i]] )
                        })
  )  
  handlers
  
}) # end of server ---- 


# UI module ------------------------------------------------------
ExistingProductUI <- function(id, product){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  box(title = as.character(product), 
      product, 
      footer = tagList(
        actionBttn(
          inputId = ns("change_selected"), label = "change"),
      )
  )
}
# server module ------------------------------------------------------
ExistingProductUpdate <- function(input, output, session, product){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  
  observeEvent(input$change_selected, {
    # when box button is clicked for this product (id)
    # FIRST: show a modal
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "what do you want to change?",
        tagList(
          radioGroupButtons(inputId = ns("change_selected_choice"), label = "change x", choices = c(1,2,3,4)),
          sliderInput(ns("change_selected_pct"), "change y:", min = -50, max = 100, value = 0, step = 5)
        ),
        easyClose = TRUE, 
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton(ns("change_selected_submit"), "submit!", icon = icon("check")),
          modalButton("never mind")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  # SECOND: when change_selected_submit is clicked, 
  observeEvent(input$change_selected_submit, {
    
    # do some calculations with product using what I inputed in modal --- 
    # then, update a table ---- 
    # functionToUploadThings(product, input$change_selected_choice)
    # THIRD: Close with a confirmation
    removeModal()
    sendSweetAlert(
      session,
      title = "Success!",
      type = "success",
      btn_labels = "Ok",
      closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
      width = NULL
    )
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please note: I made some modifications to make your MWE work:

- include `library(shinydashboard)`
- `p$title` and `product["title"]` to `product`
- change `labels` to `label` in `radioGroupButtons`
- comment out `functionToUploadThings(product, input$change_selected_choice)`

### Edit

I'm still not super sure what happens when nesting the `observeEvents`. I made a small toy example and played around with the `reactlog`. It seems that nesting the observers generates a new observer for `button2` every time `button1` is clicked. These observers are not removed and lead to unwanted behaviour. In contrast, when using separate `observeEvents`, the observer for `button2` is only created once.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactlog)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button1", "click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    print("from first observer")
    print(input$button2)
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "what do you want to change?",
        "some text",
        easyClose = TRUE, 
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton("button2", "submit!", icon = icon("check")),
          modalButton("never mind")
        )
      )
    )
    
    # nested observer -> leads to remaining observers
    observeEvent(input$button2, {
      print("from second observer")
      print(input$button2)
      removeModal()
    })
    
    
    
  })
  
  # independent observer -> generates only one observer
  # observeEvent(input$button2, {
  #   print("from second observer")
  #   print(input$button2)
  #   removeModal()
  # })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```